# Get a histogram array for the region using imhist(); [PYTHON]

Tags: python, list, numpy, image-processing, histogram

How can I get the histogram array for region that contains 4 pixels. i.e.

(x,y)   (x,y+1)

(x+1,y) (x+1,y+1)

Suppose a region contains these 4 pixels. How can I find the hiistgram array for this region in Python by using imhist();? I spent more than 5 hrs to find proper way of this but failed. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you could simply extract all four pixels from your image via slicing and then use a function like [numpy.histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) to calculate your histogram.

It would be best to provide some sort of code, what you have tried so far.